# Returned output doesn't print from a channel in Go

Tags: go, concurrency

I have an (almost) working tool which uses a pre-existing tool that does some network-intensive HTTP-based tasks against a URL.
My goal here was to run this tool against numerous hosts simultaneously and return the output, and as far as I can tell I've dealt with concurrency appropriately and I've already tested a non-concurrent version of the function called `processHTML` below.
However for some reason I'm not receiving output from the channel. Here's the code:

```golang
type Results struct {
    Host string
    Signature string
}

func main() {
    report := color.New(color.FgGreen).SprintFunc()
    success := color.New(color.FgRed).SprintFunc()

    var sec int
    flag.IntVar(&sec, "s", 360, "Specify the time to wait before moving on to next host in seconds")

    var concurrency int
    flag.IntVar(&concurrency, "t", 50, "Specify the number of threads to use")

    var file string
    flag.StringVar(&file, "f", "REQUIRED", "Set a file containing URLs to look for signatures on")
    flag.Parse()

    var tasksWG sync.WaitGroup
    tasks := make(chan string)
    output := make(chan Results)

    for i := 0; i < concurrency; i++ {
        tasksWG.Add(1)

        go func() {
            for t := range tasks {
                // run the scan
                resp, err := processHTML(t, time.Duration(sec))
                if err != nil {
                    continue
                }
                output <- resp
                continue
            }
            tasksWG.Done()
        }()

    }

    // wait for all the output to come through the channel
    var outputWG sync.WaitGroup
    outputWG.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for o := range output {
            if o.Signature == "" {
                fmt.Printf("Scanned %s\n", report(o.Host))
            } else {
                fmt.Print("Found potential finding on %s with signature: %s\n", success(o.Host), success(o.Signature))
            }
        }
        outputWG.Done()
    }()

    // waiting for tasks to complete
    go func() {
        tasksWG.Wait()
        close(output)
    }()

    // open the file
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    // filling up the kyoo
    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for s.Scan() {
        tasks <- s.Text()
    }

    close(tasks)
    outputWG.Wait()
}

func processHTML(t string, sec time.Duration) (Results, error) {
    var r Results
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), sec * time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "./resources/processHTML.py", "-u", t)
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return r, err
    }
    cmd.Start()

    s := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    for s.Scan() {
        l := s.Text()
        if strings.Contains(l, "some signature") {
            f := strings.Fields(l)
            r = Results{f[7], f[5]}
            // this prints what I'm looking for
        //  fmt.Println(r)
        }
        // otherwise we still want to keep track of what we've done
        r = Results{t, ""}
    }
    cmd.Wait()
    return r, err
}
```

That script in `./resources/processHTML.py` is a python script which looks at HTTP responses and it takes a matter of seconds to a minute or three to finish.
I can `fmt.Println(r)` and get the results.
I want just fine, but for some reason even if the data in `Results{f[7], f[5]}` exists, the only thing that comes out of the output channel is the data from outside of the `if strings.Contains()` block.

I would love it if someone could enlighten me on why this is happening. Thank you!

EDIT: Here's the super simple solution to this problem:

```golang
for s.Scan() {
    l := s.Text()
    // show all the output of smuggler.py (you psycho)
    if debug {
        fmt.Println(l)
    }

    // check for connection error 
    if strings.Contains(l, "Unable to connect to host") {
        r.Error = strings.Split(l, ":")[1]
    }

    // otherwise, if we found something
    if strings.Contains(l, "some signature") {
        f := strings.Fields(l)
        r.Payload = f[5]
    }
    r.Host = t
}
```

Comment: What's the last loop supposed to do? The one at the bottom? It looks like it does a plain assign... Do you expect that loop to iterate only once? Or do you care only about the result of the last iteration? And what's the purpose of the `strings.Contains` block, if after that block, you re-assign `r` anyway? i.e. `r = Results{f[7], f[5]}` is ALWAYS overwritten after the `if` block.

Comment: No, I don't only care about the last iteration so I basically made a silly mistake on my part. Thanks for catching that I'll update the code with the solution.